# Yii2 Testing: How to run module tests along with main app test?

Tags: testing, yii2, codeception, yii2-extension, yii2-module

I want to run my main application Codeception tests and have it automatically go through the tests provided by 3rd party modules (assuming they come with their own Codeception configurations) installed through composer (which means they are living in the `vendor/` folder).

I don't know how this can be done. Do I need to provide some kind of Codeception run parameters? Do I have to modify the bootstrap files? Does Codeception even support something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeception can include other test suites by using include setting in codeception.yml

Documentation: http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization

Example:

```
include:
  - vendor/vendor1/lib1
  - vendor/vendor1/lib2
  - vendor/vendor2/lib3
```

Comment: This works. But it always runs the tests after the ones from the root `codeception.yml`. Do you happen to know of any way to execute the included ones first?

Comment: the test should be like that, all must be tested so that no errors occur in the application as a whole. If you are making one tester and whether the tester is running well or not, you only comment on the unused lines in "include:".